# biblatex-apa -- biber

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, texmaker, biber

I'm using LaTeX for four days now and I have a problem with the `biblatex-apa` style.

Here is the important part of my header:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    12pt,
    %twocolumn,
    headings=normal     % big,small
]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    top=3.5cm,
    left=2.3cm,
    right=4.5cm,
    bottom=4.5cm,}

\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{literatur}        
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\begin{document}

\cite{example}

\end{document}
```

I'm using Texmaker and BibTeX. And it doesn't work. :( There are undefinded references and I should rerun Biber on the file (`biblatex`) apa (`biblatex`) and rerun LaTeX afterwards. I already tried to run `bibtex`, `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, but nothing changed.

Can somebody please help me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short: If you define `backend=biber` then you should actually use `biber` as your backend and not `bibtex`. Or you can define `backend=bibtex` and use `bibtex`.

Longer: `biber` is a program specifically meant to replace `bibtex` (the program) for `biblatex`. It does everything `bibtex` does and much more. Among other things it can handle UTF8 encoded files flawlessly, supports advanced sorting mechanisms and can do all kind of funky on-the-fly manipulation. If there's nothing which forces you to use `bibtex`, use `biber` (which is part of `TeXLive` and `MikTeX`)

BTW: The sequence is `latex`, `biber` (or `bibtex`), `latex`. You always must run `latex` first because only after a `latex` run, the system actually "knows" that there are references.

EDIT: Since `biblatex-apa` requires `biber`, using the `BibTeX` backend is not an option in this particular case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I get biber? 
I already searched in the web and am a bit confused now. Is biber the same as biblatex?
How does my header change? Is this the correct part of the header:


\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biber}
\bibliography{literatur}        
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}

\begin{document}
\cite{example}
\end{document}

Comment: @Markus -- Change `\bibliography{literatur}` to `\addbibresource{literatur.bib}`.  Biber is available [here](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/). Biber is a program, like BibTeX, but is designed specifically for biblatex (which is a 'package' for LaTeX): biber can only be used with biblatex, which is not true of bibtex.

Comment: As I wrote: You can use `bibtex` but then you have to change the backend directive. If you leave your preamble as it is, you must use `biber` which is part of both `TeXLive`and `MikTeX`. If you have troubling finding it, we need to know what distribution and what editor you actually use. While the use of `\addbibresource`is encouraged, this is not the cause of your problem. `\bibliography` will work as well.

Comment: I'm using Texmaker from MikTex and I think biber should be already installed. 
Even if i let compile the header with this part: 
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literatur.bib}        
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} i get three warning (citation undefined, undefined references, please rerun biber on the file). But it doesn't matter how often I compile with pdflatex and bibtex, the warnings persist and biblatex doesn't work.

Comment: Again: if you have `backend=biber` in your document, don't use `bibtex` but `biber` instead. I'm not a TeXMaker user, but after a short glimpse at the program it looks like you must change the settings for the Bib(la)tex command. In my vanilla installation it says `"/usr/texbin/bibtex" %.aux`. You probably have to change this to `"/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf` (not tested, and this is with TeXMaker under `TeXLive` on OSX. YMMV). Or, if you want to continue using `bibtex`, change the backend line in your .tex document to `backend=bibtex`.

Comment: unfortunately the ending backend=bibtex doens't work neither, perhabs it is a problem with compatibility

Comment: now it's working, i had to configure texmaker

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. `biblatex-apa` requires `biber` (which is no big surprise, since the author of `biblatex-apa` is also the main author of `biber`). Good that you succeeded in configuring TeXMaker.

Comment: @Markus: Can you explain what you actually did to solve the problem? I'm having the exact same problem as you and I can't get it working.